# Индикатор загрузки в качестве GIF картинки

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, анимация, gif

В процессе обработки информации, мне бы хотелось получить отдельное всплывающее окно, в котором зациклено изображение gif. Для выполнения этой задачи я пытаюсь использовать Task.

*Представленный ниже код работает, но только по завершении загрузки.*

Мне бы хотелось увидеть его сразу, по вызову метода.

```
    public void add_anu(Stage stage_test_go){

    Task task =  new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    stage_test_go.show();
                    stage_test_go.setResizable(false);
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).run();

}
```

Comment: Должно быть наоборот - в таске должен выполняться "медленный"  код обработки, а окно показывается как обычно.

Comment: Ruslan P. благодарю за ответ, но я не совсем понимаю, что мне необходимо исправить ?

Comment: Приведенного куска кода недостаточно, предполагаю, у вас там загружается файл по сети или что-то в этом роде, так вот, именно этот код должен выполнятся таской в отдельном потоке - запускаете таску в новом потоке, показываете окно с гифкой, в конце выполнения загрузки скрываете окно с гифкой.

Comment: Всё теперь понял ) Огромное спасибо!